# Reference disappearing mysteriously when I compile

Tags: .net, reference, exchange-server

I have a program in which I need to get emails from our exchange server. I got this from an old project :

```
Dim oExchService As New ExchangeService(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1)
                    oExchService.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(strUserName, strPassword, strDomain)
                    oExchService.Url = New Uri(strServeur)

                    Dim oItemView As New ItemView(1000)
                    oItemView.Traversal = ItemTraversal.Shallow

                    Dim oLstItems As FindItemsResults(Of Item) = oExchService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, oItemView)
                    'Importation de chaque fichier
                    For Each oItem As Item In oLstItems
                        If oItem.HasAttachments Then

                        End If
                    Next
```

I added the reference to Microsoft.Exchange.webservice.dll which I also got from the other project and imports the reference in the file. Everything seems fine and I can work with the member inside the classe. When I hit compile where as the imports statetement get green underlined stating the reference doens't exists or doesn't have any public members...

Anybody know what's going on ?

Comment: Not sure what's going on. I installed from NuGet and couldn't reproduce the issue. You could try using NuGet to install, as well. Search for exchangewebservices (all one word) to get the dll.

Comment: Tried it but I got the exact same result. As long as I don't compilie I can use it no problem. As soon as I hit play, it's like it disapears completly and will not work. Mind you I can access everything before compiling (I got the intellisense)

Comment: So I finally made it work, but this is the first time I saw this and  the last I hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright,

In the end, it was the target framework.

this Worked : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/26f1a426-f42d-4bab-8245-1a77c3f09251